# Is there an analogous tool as "cuptea" (ubuntu) in XFCE

Tags: ubuntu, xfce, screensaver

I use occasionally ubuntu 20.04. In the right corner there is an icon like a "cuptea". When you click it it disables the screensaver and hibernation (see screenshot).
[image]
Is there an equivalent in XFCE?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain exactly what features you need. The screenshot just shows us a tiny little button, that doesn't give any information. Can you describe what features you want? What should happen when you click the button? There may be other tools, or it could be scriptable, but we need to know what you need.

Comment: Seems like a clone of caffeine

Comment: @terdon I describe it in the question.

Comment: So you want something that when clicked disables the screensaver, blocks hibernation, but allows suspending? Or should it also block suspending? How about shutting down?And for how long? Until you click it again? For a specific amount of time?

Comment: terdon: I just want to disable automatic hipernation and screensaver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want/need the caffeine app. It's in the app store and I believe you can also install it via sudo apt install caffeine

Comment: As you suggested, it seems I want to install caffeine-like program in XFCE4. It seems that caffeine is gnome-related program but the fork `caffeine-ng` [https://codeberg.org/WhyNotHugo/caffeine-ng]. Anyway it seems that XFCE has a presentation mode [https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-power-manager/4.16/panel-plugin] which disables this. Reference: https://forum.tuxdigital.com/t/does-xfce-have-a-feature-like-caffeine-espresso/4750